# Tweepy 2.1: Add member to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

Using Tweepy2.1, I am trying to add a member (*people*) of my Twitter account to a list (*testlist*) with:

```
import tweepy

...

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.add_list_member(testlist, people)
```

I get the following error:

```
TweepError: [{'message': 'You must specify either a list ID or a slug and owner', 'code': 112}]
```

I have tried other ways of calling the `add_list_member` function, but nothing worked. Also, I have some difficulties with the incomplete Tweepy documentation.

Anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: What are `testlist` and `people`?

Comment: testlist: twitter list (slug) / people: twitter friend (screen_name)

Comment: I mean, what are their values? What do `repr(testlist)` and `repr(people)` output?

Comment: these are strings, and repr returns the input / api.add_list_member('listname','friendscreenname')

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add what has been explained by Charles.
You can also add list member by his/her user id.

```
api.add_list_member(user_id=1234, slug='testlist', owner_screen_name='@myTwitterName')
```

Please review the parameters in tweepy api [1](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py)

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the 'slug' or text label/name of the list. For this to work you also need to provide the account that the list is owned by. You can specify the owner with keyword arguments.

`api.add_list_member(screen_name='@userToAdd', slug='testlist', owner_screen_name='@myTwitterName')`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post, but I kept getting an error with the above solutions. This is what worked for me using tweepy 3.5:

```
api.add_list_member(screen_name=screen_name, list_id=list_id)
```