# Tweepy Error when adding member to the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Looking at the following code

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.add_list_member('listslugname', '@twitterhandleto_add')
```

Is throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./twitter_client.py", line 26, in <module>
    api.add_list_member('testl', '@twitterhandleto_add')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'You must specify either a list ID or a slug and owner.', u'code': 112}]
```

FYI: Python V 2.7 and Tweepy : 3.7

Please help

Comment: Had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809356/tweepy-how-to-add-user-to-specific-list too, coud't get to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer from this.

ls = api.add_list_member(screen_name='@usertoadd', slug='listslug', owner_screen_name='@ownerthatsyou')

Ref:
[Tweepy 2.1: Add member to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213285/tweepy-2-1-add-member-to-a-list)